# make object move from 1 point to another at a custom speed

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I made an app which there is an object that moves towards a moving point all the time - that is why I didn't use any animated function. The problem is that I made this function:

```
CGPoint center = self.im.center; // "i" is a CGPoint, im is an imageview.
if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(self.im.center, i))
{
    a = (i.y-center.y)/(i.x-center.x);
    //Y = a*X+b - this is a linear function in math
    b = (center.y-(a*center.x));
    if (i.y>center.y) {
        self.im.center = CGPointMake(((center.y+1)-b)/a, center.y+1);
    }
    else
    {
        self.im.center = CGPointMake(((center.y-1)-b)/a, center.y-1);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the closer the functions is becoming a straight horizontal line its faster because the change is mostly to the X axis which means that if I add 1 to Y the change to X is bigger which means it will move faster..

If there is another way to do this i will be glad to try it so if you know other ways tell me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a different solution

```
CGPoint center = self.im.center;//im = the image view
x = center.x;//starting point
y = center.y;//starting point
double distance = sqrtf(powf(i.x - x, 2) + powf(i.y - y, 2));// i = cgpoint (ending point)
float speedX = (2 * (i.x - x)) / distance;//(the 2 is the speed)
float speedY = (2 * (i.y - y)) / distance;//(the 2 is the speed)
self.im.center = CGPointMake(center.x+speedX, center.y+speedY);//im = the image view
```